# Wanna know the how the compiler is processing this piece of code

Tags: python, list

Here's the piece of code-
I just wanna know how the compiler is processing line 5 here. Like I wanna know in detail what's happening in line 5 (e=b[d]).

```
import random
a=input("Please type some names- ")
b=a.split(",")
c=len(b)
d=random.randint(0,c-1)
e=b[d]
print(e)
```

Comment: What do you think that line is doing?

Comment: There's no much to say. `b[d]` is implemented with `b.__getitem__(d)`.

Comment: dis.dis can show you the bytecode

Comment: I think they are asking more generally "what does this code do" rather than anything deeper. At least looking at their prior python questions

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I'm just trying to know what exactly happening in line 6

Answer (score 1):

As you asked in your comment above, line 6 accesses a list, b, at index d, d is a random integer from the range 0 to the length of the list.